# How to access a linux shell from my phone via bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, linux, ssh, shell

Basically I want to send shell commands from my phone to my PC (Ubuntu 11.10) via bluetooth. Why? Because I don't always have WLAN and WLAN on my phone sucks.

All possible solutions are welcome. I know that most solutions will require some kind of daemon running on the linux system. This is no problem.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** I will not root my phone.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can, but the steps may be a little bit complicated, see the following blog post about [ssh-ing over bluetooth](http://geeksheadaches.blogspot.com/2009/02/pan-and-ssh-android-phone.html).

Comment: Thanks for this, but see EDIT. :)